# What is the role of Angular.js in Rubyonrails development any alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started learning rubyonrails but I heard about Angular.js.

Any alternative or it is compulsory to learn with rubyonrails.

or I can develop webapps without angular.js

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails and Angular.js are two different things. Ruby on Rails is a framework for the server side of a web application written in Ruby, Angular.js is a javascript framework for the client side of a web application. They can be used independently, or together.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly broad question, however I'll give some general information on Angular's role within a Rails context, as well as brief info on what else is out there.

AngularJS is not required to develop web apps with Ruby on Rails. Rails is its own framework, one that handles both front end and back end functionality. In fact, to use Angular with Rails, you'd have to prevent Rails from handling the front-end aspect, and have it act as an API provider which Angular would then use to provide an interface.

Angular is a front-end framework - it is generally used to hook up to a backend like Rails, and the two can work in conjunction, though it's certainly not required. You're able to build out full applications in Rails entirely, and can build Angular applications without ever touching Rails. This being said, Angular is not the only framework of its kind, there are several great ones out there:

- [**Backbone.js**](http://backbonejs.org/) - a library which provides a ton of flexibility for the developer in how to structure their app; it's fairly non opinionated and depending on your style that can be either great or not so great.
- [**Ember.js**](http://emberjs.com/) - a "framework for creating ambitious apps", as put in Ember's own words. It's an opinionated framework, and if you're experienced in Rails you'd definitely see similarities between the two frameworks in terms of conventions.
- [**React.js**](https://facebook.github.io/react/) - a JS library for building user interfaces - it's basically like the V in the MVC framework, handling only the views.

There's no need to learn any of these to be able to use Rails to build fully functional apps. If you want to build snappy single page applications, then learning to use/integrate one of the front-end frameworks/libraries with Rails would be a good idea.

Hope it helps!